# Error when making HTTP GET request in Go: "dial tcp: lookup api.ipify.org on [::1]:53: read udp [::1]:50975->[::1]:53: read: connection refused"

Tags: go, http, request, get

I'm trying to make an HTTP GET request in Go using the `net/http` package to retrieve my public IP address using the api.ipify.org service. I'm encountering an error only after I build the application using the following command:

```bash
CGO_ENABLED=0 GOOS=linux go build -a -ldflags "-s -w" -o ip get.go
```

However, I noticed that the code works perfectly fine when I use either of the following commands:

```bash
go build get.go
```

```bash
go run get.go
```

Here's the code I'm using:

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "io/ioutil"
    "net/http"
)

func get() {
    resp, err := http.Get("https://api.ipify.org")
    if err == nil {
        defer resp.Body.Close()
        bodyBytes, _ := ioutil.ReadAll(resp.Body)
        body := string(bodyBytes)
        fmt.Println(body)
    } else {
        fmt.Println(err)
    }
}

func main() {
    get()
}
```

It's perplexing to me why the code works with `go build` and `go run` but fails when I use the more complex build command. Could someone please help me understand what might be causing this issue and how I can resolve it? Thank you for your time and assistance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When cgo is available, the cgo-based resolver is used. It uses various way to resolve the domain that is reading /etc/resolv.conf or /etc/nsswitch.conf, etc. These features are not implemented by Go based DNS resolver therefore resulting in failure to resolve the domain and HTTP request fails.